# php code to select and display page no between given range from database

Tags: php, mysql

tablename     page_no

column name  page1 , page2

i am storing value like 
page1 --  2

page2 --  12 in database like wise.
value is inserted from textbox and it can be any.

**now my question is how to display page no between range of 2 to 12 from database.
for ex --  2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.**

**below is my code but it is only display increment page no.
but i want to display incremented pageno between given range only.**

```
               <?php         
                $sqlpage = "SELECT * FROM page_no";             
                $resultpage = mysql_query($sqlpage);                
                if($rowpage = mysql_fetch_array($resultpage, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                 for($i=0;$i<$rowpage['pageno'];$i++)
                 {              
                 ?>
        <tr>                    
<td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i+1; ?></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909214/how-to-generate-and-display-serial-number-between-min-and-max-value-in-php/25909432#25909432.. Duplicate

Answer (score 0):

check the case also see the comment on your question you are using deprecated functions

```
<?php         
                $sqlpage = "SELECT * FROM page_no";             
                $resultpage = mysql_query($sqlpage);                
                if($rowpage = mysql_fetch_array($resultpage, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                 for($i=0;$i<$rowpage['pageno'];$i++)
                 {    
                   if($i>=$lower_bound && $i<=$upper_bound){
                           $page+=$i+",";}

                 ?>
        <tr>                    
<td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $page; ?></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

where `$lower_bound` is lower limit like 2 in your case and `$upper_bound` is upper like 12 in your case

Comment: i implemented this code but this is now fetching and display number in increment form.   for ex-- if i insert 1 in lower bound and and 12 in upper bound then i want to fetch from 1 to 12, and loop row upto reached at upper bound and display like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 in 12 different rows. plz suggest me how to do this and display numbers in 12 different rows.