# how to generate and display serial number between min and max value in php

Tags: php, mysql

Tablename       **page_no**

column name       **min, max**

i am storing value like min = 2 ,max = 12
  in database like wise. value is inserted from textbox and it can be any.

**i need a for loop to fetch data between min and max value.
i cannot understand how to pass our min and max column in for loop**

and how to display page no between range of 2 to 12 from database. for ex -- 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.

for ex---

i have two textbox in my form .textbox name is min and max. i am inserting value from textboxes. for ex min - 1 and max - 14 or any value like this. now i want to fetch value from database between min and max and display 1,2,3,4,5, etc upto max value in different rows. fir ex if i insert min=1 and max=14 then it display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 no. in 14 different rows.

below is my code

```
<?php         
    $sqlpage = "SELECT * FROM page_no";             
    $resultpage = mysql_query($sqlpage);                
    if($rowpage = mysql_fetch_array($resultpage, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        for($i=0;$i<$rowpage['min'];$i++)
        {    
            if($i>=$min && $i<=$max)
            {
?>
                <tr>                    
                    <td><?php echo $i+1; ?></td>
                </tr> 
 <?php 
             }
     } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=$rowpage['min'];$i<$rowpage['max'];$i++)
        {
                <tr>                    
                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                </tr>     
        }
```

Get your **$i** as min number and loop until it lower than the max number. Print the result